# async bcrypt post request returns no response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-router, bcrypt

I am trying to compare password in order to login user, but i keep getting "this request has no response."

this is my post route.

```
router.route("/login/:username1").post(async (req, res) => {
  const userexist = User.find(username=>userexist.username=req.body.username1)
      if(userexist == null) 
      {
        return res.status(400).json("Cannot find user");
      }
      try 
      {
        if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userexist.password))
        {
          res.json("success");
        }
        else
        {
          res.json("Not Allowed");
        }
      } catch {
        res.status(500).json();
      }
});
```

this is my post method from my login page.

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isValid = this.validate();
    const username1=this.state.username;
    if (isValid) {
      const user = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      };

      axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/users/login/"+ username1, user)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
      this.setState(initialState);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `username=>userexist.username`? Maybe do you mean `user => user.username`?

Comment: i don't think so i am trying to search by the username if i do that then i don't get the username that is passed in the body. that would be a null username rite? i think maybe it has something to do with the search params too.

Comment: `userexist` is undefined inside filter function. So the correct code will be `const userexist = User.find (user => user.username == req.body.username1)`. P.S. Yes, there is an another one error: use `==` instead `=` to compare.

Comment: thanks but when i post the request it breaks the mongo db connection. and it didn't accept == to compare it required === weird..and shouldn't user be username instead as it is in my schema?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just incise anyone has the same issue.
the problem was the `user.password` it was returning an array which had to be accessed like so `user[0]['password']` it now works fine. i am using react router and also i have my MongoDB connection via a .env file which is used by my MongoDB models.js schema.

```
User.find({ username: req.body.username }).then(async (user)  => {
     if( user.length>0) {
         await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0]['password'], 
         function(err, result) {

         if(result){
            res.send('success') ;
          }else{

           res.send('not allowed') ;
         }
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make few corrections and see how you go:

- use await in your controller
- With below line of code, you are sending user object. So in your controller, use **req.body.username** (not req.body.username1)

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/login/"+ username1, user)
```

- make correction to your `find` function as shown in the code snippet
- also check your cors and make sure that client is adhering server cors rules

```
router.route("/login/:username1").post(async (req, res) => {
    const userexist = await User.find(user=>user.username==req.body.username) //<---- make correction to find method ... use await and use correct req body object i.e. username not username1
        if(userexist == null) 
        {
          return res.status(400).json("Cannot find user");
        }
        try 
        {
          if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userexist.password))
          {
            res.send("success"); //<----- as best practice, while sending strings just use res.send('success')... res.json is not reqd
          }
          else
          {
            res.send("Not Allowed"); //<----- for strings, it is better to use res.send instead of res.json
          }
        } catch {
          res.status(500).json(); //<----- remember to pass meaningful error message back to client
        }
  });
```